# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when trying to connect to api through proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a website, and lately I had to change the web address. When the user first enters "http://name-of_the.website.pl", he is greeted with login screen. This part is working perfectly. As soon as the user enters credentials and hits the login button, the website throws ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

The login page is trying to connect to api (deployed in the same docker swarm) through nginx proxy (code below). After inspecting proxy logs I have found this:

> 2021-11-11 18:02:05 +0000 2021/11/11 18:02:05 [error] 15#15: *192 config.json could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 10.0.0.2, server: ~^proxy\.name-of_the\.website\.pl$, request: "GET /config.json HTTP/1.1

The whole thing used to work great before changing the host name.

Answer (score 0):

So everything was fine with my proxy and the website. The reason it did not work was the fact that the website was trying to connect to local proxy while it was on the server somewhere else. All I had to do was add the address of the server hosting the proxy and the rest of the app to hosts file on my machine.